# SQL name checking function SSMS

Tags: sql, ssms

How to make the function take on a value only when the characters of the English and Russian alphabets are used.
And all other values containing:

1. numbers
2. special characters
3. the number of characters is less than 2 and more than 50 - the function did not accept

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.namecheck(@name VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS BIT AS BEGIN 
IF 
PATINDEX('%[a-z][A-Z][а-я][А-Я]%', @name) = 0
RETURN 1;
ELSE IF 
(LEN(@name) < 2 OR LEN(@name) > 50) 
RETURN 0
RETURN 0
END;
```

i wrote like this but it doesn't work right, It accepts names containing numeric values ,  special characters

Comment: “*it doesn’t work right*” is not a very helpful problem statement. *What about it doesn’t work “right”*? See [ask]

Comment: Invert the logic; the function should *not* accept if a character occurs that is *not* in the set, that is, `LIKE N'%[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]'` (and use `N` for Unicode, of course -- and `NVARCHAR(50)`, since Cyrillic characters are unlikely to fit in the default collation).

Answer (score 0):

Exit with false when it's not okay.

And then just return true by default, since the checks didn't find anything wrong.

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.namecheck(@name VARCHAR(51))
> RETURNS BIT AS 
> BEGIN 
>
>   IF (LEN(@name) < 2 OR LEN(@name) > 50)
>     RETURN 0;
>     
>   IF @name LIKE '%[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]%'
>     RETURN 0;
>
>   RETURN 1;
> END;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select col, dbo.namecheck(col) chk
> from (values
>    ('ab'), ('AЯ'), (N'abcЯ'),
>    ('AB.cd'), 
>    ('ABCD001'),
>    (replicate('X', 55))
>  ) q(col)
> ```

> ```
> col                                                     | chk  
> :------------------------------------------------------ | :----
> ab                                                      | True 
> A?                                                      | True 
> abcЯ                                                   | True 
> AB.cd                                                   | False
> ABCD001                                                 | False
> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | False
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d9edcdc036b4a894fcbec9146145fb4d)*